# How to use switch case according my condition in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

```
 if($this->input->get('i1')!='' && $this->input->get('i2')=='' && $this->input->get('i3')=='' && $this->input->get('i4')=='')
            {
                echo 'i1';
            }else
            if($this->input->get('i1')!='' && $this->input->get('i2')!='' && $this->input->get('i3')=='' && $this->input->get('i4')=='')
            {
                echo 'i1  i2 ';
            }else
            if($this->input->get('i1')!='' && $this->input->get('i2')!='' && $this->input->get('i3')!='' && $this->input->get('i4')=='')
            {
                echo 'i1 i2 i3';
            }else
            if($this->input->get('i1')!='' && $this->input->get('i2')!='' && $this->input->get('i3')!='' && $this->input->get('i4')!='')
            {
                echo 'i1 i2 i3 i4';
            }
```

How to use this condition in switch case... Any one can help me.

Comment: Hi, did you try to do it? Please look at the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I have faced lots of if else conditions ... And want change to all condition on  Switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to generate like a bitmask.

The defines are just to make the code more readable.

```
// create costants to make the code more readable           
define('I1', '1000'); 
define('I1_I2', '1100'); 
define('I1_I2_I3', '1110'); 
define('I1_I2_I3_I4', '1111'); 

// controll you input and cast in iteger
// true  -> 1
// false -> 0
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $var  = 'i' . $i;
    $$var =  $this->input->get($var)
    $$var = (int) !empty($$var);
}

// generate a mask
// eg : 1000
$mask = $i1.$i2.$i3.$i4;

switch ($mask) {
    case I1:
        echo 'i1';
        break;
    case I1_I2:
        echo 'i1 i2';
        break;
    case I1_I2_I3:
        echo 'i1 i2 i3';
        break;
    case I1_I2_I3_I4:
        echo 'i1 i2 i3';
        break;
}
```

Comment: empty($this->input->get('i1')) not working With $this->input->get('i1') ;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a switch case, but since you clarified that you are looking to simplify, would this work for your needs?

```
for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++){
    if(!empty($this->input->get('i'.$x)) echo "i$x ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a answer, But following also look less lengthy.

```
if($this->input->get('i1')!='')
{
    echo 'i1 ';
    if($this->input->get('i2')!='')
    {
        echo 'i2 ';
        if($this->input->get('i3')!='')
        {
            echo 'i3 ';
            if($this->input->get('i4')!='')
            {
                echo 'i4 ';
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a switch case helps much with simplification here. Instead I suggest a more dynamic solution. Something like this:

```
$inputs = $this->input->only('i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4');
$notEmptyInputs = array_filter($inputs);
echo implode(' ', array_keys($notEmptyInputs));
```

If you don't want an output like `i1 i4` but only `i1` if 2 and 3 are not set, use this:

```
$inputs = $this->input->only('i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4');
$notEmptyInputs = [];
foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
    if(empty($value)){
        break;
    }
    $notEmptyInputs[] = $key;
}
echo implode(' ', $notEmptyInputs);
```